Illegal Hardware Instruction in JetSon Nano
Currently, I'm working with Jetson Nano 2Gb, and I facing the problem about assembly when I debug with gdb, I receive
92      __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %[res], daif": [res] "=r" (res)::);
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
INTERRUPTS_ENABLED () at Sx1278.cpp:92

And this is assembly code that causing that bug
__inline__ int INTERRUPTS_ENABLED(void) {
    int res;
    __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %[res], daif": [res] "=r" (res)::);
    return ((res >> 7) & 1) == 0;
}

__inline__ void ENABLE_INTERRUPTS(void) {
    if (!INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()) {
        __asm__ __volatile__("msr daifset, #2");
    }
}

__inline__ void DISABLE_INTERRUPTS(void) {
    if (INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()) {
        __asm__ __volatile__("msr daifclr, #2");
    }
}

I think this code have a problem in __inline__ int INTERRUPTS_ENABLE(void); function. But I don't have any idea to fix it.
I have no experience with this problem.
I use this repo to control gpio pin
https://github.com/Rubberazer/JETGPIO
Some information about my project:
I need to communicate between module Sx1278 (LoRa) and Jetson Nano board.
This is my github for Jetson Nano and module LoRa Ra-02:
github
It's include Makefile. I just modify some function based on this repo
To running this program, I only use makefile, that generate executable file. I thought it's caused by toolchain, but I can't fix it.
Some information: When I use OS raspbian 32 bit it run normally. But when I use OS 64 bit, it's facing that problem, and my module run on Aarch64 architecture. Jetson Nano don't just have os version 64 bit.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem when using the JETGPIO library on a 64-bit Jetson Nano or another Aarch64 system? Any suggestions on how to diagnose and fix this issue would be immensely helpful.

What is x/i $pc  at the time of the crash?

daif can only be read from EL0 if SCTLR_EL1.UMA is set to 1.  Maybe that is not the case?

Hi @Jester, ```=> 0x555555a38c <INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()+4>:       mrs     x0, daif
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
INTERRUPTS_ENABLED () at Sx1278.cpp:91
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x555555a38c <INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()+4>:       mrs     x0, daif
this isx/i $pc``` at the time of the crash

Hi @fuz, I think that register causing that bug, I haven't set SCTLR_EL1.UMA  register yet, how can fix it?

The kernel needs to set that, but I a not familiar with the conditions under which it does.

oh, thanks for your support. I will try to solve it
